# Pipes vented to patio

Tags: natural-gas

I have gas pipes being vented into a fenced in patio area.

3 years ago , I called the fire department as the gas meter inside was reading too high as I was getting dizzy. I can no longer open the windows in the kitchen as the pipe is under them.

Today, I was sweeping my patio area and the  exhaust came on. I immediately got dizzy and left the area. The gate was open so I thought it would be ok but obviously it wasn't.

Are there regulations on installing these pipes as the fire department didn't seem to have enough experience with it.

I live in New Brunswick.

I'm in the process of buying long extension pipes. Why would the gas company be permitted to install them in this location?

Thanks

Comment: Are these gas pipes connected to your gas *regulator* by chance? It sounds like you may need to call your gas utility in on this one, as it could be that the regulator is venting gas....

Comment: *Gas pipes contain gas*, they are sealed and are not vented in any way. The gas needs to be contained within the pipes until it reaches the appliance and is burned to produce heat or combustion. Appliances that use gas vent the exhaust, a product of the combustion of gas out of the house through vent pipes. **Can you edit your question to clarify if you are talking about VENTING PIPES ?**

Comment: please add a picture of the gas pipes ... also, describe what you mean by `gate`

Answer (score 1):

#### Carbon Monoxide

While anything is possible, and I have heard of people claiming to be sensitive to natural gas itself, what typically causes problems are the products of **combustion** of natural gas. That matches with "the exhaust came on". So the rest of this answer is based on the problem NOT being a natural gas leak (which would be often under control or at least supervision of the local natural gas utility) but rather a carbon monoxide or other combustion problem.

When a natural gas appliance (furnace, cooktop, water heater, generator, etc.) is running, the primary combustion products are water and carbon **dioxide**. However, if natural gas (or other carbon fuels) does not burn properly, due to insufficient oxygen or equipment malfunction, carbon **monoxide (CO)** can be produced. Carbon dioxide is harmless in small amounts but in large amounts can cause problems. **Carbon monoxide is harmful even at low levels and can be fatal.** CO is odorless and colorless and symptoms of CO poisoning are similar to the flu and often, tragically, not spotted in time. (And recently used as a way to nearly kill the main characters in a science fiction novel, [https://www.amazon.com/Delta-v-Daniel-Suarez/dp/1524742414](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1524742414) , but I digress...)

The detection and resolution of a carbon monoxide problem, unlike a natural gas leak, is typically the responsibility of the homeowner and not the utility. Which means calling in a qualified HVAC technician to check the equipment and repair, replace or redesign portions of it as needed. The most important thing is to make sure that under normal operation, there is no significant amount of carbon monoxide either inside (e.g., near the furnace) or outside (the exhaust pipes). Assuming that is resolved, then there are two additional things to do:

- Consider extending/redirecting the exhaust pipe for **carbon dioxide**. It is possible that if you are outside near the exhaust and it is running properly that the carbon dioxide could affect you. It shouldn't be a big problem, but if you have ruled out carbon monoxide then that is a possibility and the exhaust should be directed farther away. Typically it will be directed **up** as well - e.g., through the roof, though that may not always be an option.
- Add carbon monoxide detectors. You should have one one on each level, and one not too far from any natural gas appliances. This is important because a combination of incomplete combustion combined with a cracked heat exchanger could result in carbon monoxide **inside your house**.

Comment: Can not see how or why they would be near a window.

Comment: @RobertMoody "I can no longer open the windows in the kitchen as the pipe is under them" Why? I don't know. But that appears to be the case.